# Rethrow custom exceptions in several methods C++11

Tags: python, function, c++11, decorator

I have a use case where I have to catch various exception that can be thrown and pass an equivalent exception from my library

example:

```
def subscribe() {
    try {
       .....
       .....
    catch (A e) { throw new MY_A(e);}
    catch (B e) { throw new MY_B(e);}
    catch (C e) { throw new MY_C(e);}
    catch(...) { throw default(e)}
}
```

I wanted to do this for several methods - subscribe, unsubscribe, stop, start etc., Is there any easy way of doing this ?

Had it been in python, I would have simply written a decorator and achieved this. What will be the easy way to do this in C++11 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use [`std::current_exception()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/current_exception) to get a handle on the current exception in a `catch(...)` block. Combining that with the fact that default arguments are evaluated at the point of a function call, we can do the following:

```
void common_exception_handler(std::exception_ptr eptr = std::current_exception()) {
    try {
        if (eptr) {
            std::rethrow_exception(eptr);
        }
    }
    catch (A const &e) {throw MY_A(e);}
    catch (B const &e) {throw MY_B(e);}
    catch (C const &e) {throw MY_C(e);}
}

void subscribe() {
    try {
        ...
    }
    catch (...) {common_exception_handler();}
}
```

Comment: But here too I have to add a try catch block for all the methods.

Comment: But only once, your `unsubscribe()`, `stop()` and `start()` functions only have to call `common_exception_handler()`. Consider `catch(...) {common_exception_handler();}` to be the decorator.